# How to log in social networking sites like facebook, twitter and google+ to my websites in Zend Framework 1.12?

Tags: php, facebook, zend-framework, twitter, google-plus

How to integrate the Social websites Facebook, twitter and Google+ in our website .

When a user comes to use an application in our website he must first log in through any of the above website, how this can be done using zend framework 1.12?

Is there any plugin combine available for the three websites? Or how can this be done?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

needed to write a login procedure so that people could login with either Facebook, Twitter or Google. It is also possible to login with a combinations of these providers at the same time, so you could make use of multiple API’s. This way you could for example post a tweet (Twitter) and a wallpost (Facebook) for your user at the same time.

You can find code [here](https://github.com/thebestsolution/ZendMultipleAuthentications):

Update: demo online at http://thebestsolution.org/projects/ZendMultipleAuthentications/. Your data is not saved, it is just a proof of concept!

Facebook

For Facebook login OAuth 2.0 is used. This is a really nice and simplistic protocol for authentication, but Zend has not (yet) implemented it in the framework. So I wrote a consumer class to handle the Oauth2 requests. To use the API of Facebook I made my own Facebook Resource class.

Twitter

Twitter uses the OAuth 1.0 protocol Zend already has classes to handle the OAuth 1.0 behavior.
To access the API the Twitter Resource class is used.

Google

Google has multiple options for authentication. I first tried the OAuth 2.0, but this isn’t useful for login because it doesn’t remember the permissions the user has agreed on for accessing resources. So every time the user authenticate the question is asked to give permission to the users Google resources. I gave up and used the OpenId protocol which could not only provide a login service but also could access some of the user info. Zend has classes for the OpenId protocol and they are used to connect with Google.
The OpenId consumer in the Zend Framework doesn’t support Google. Follow instructions from this comment.

*Update: Google has changed their authorization protocol for OAuth2 (link). Now Google remembers authorization given for OAuth2 resources so I changed the code to use OAuth2 instead of OpenID for Google login. We can use the Google API with the Google Resource class.

Comment: The TBS file in the library is empty. The are no files in that folder, can you provide those files @abhisheksuthar

Comment: Ya. I didn't find any files in TBS. I am getting the following error :                       Class 'TBS\Auth' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\zendfblogin\application\controllers\UserController.php on line 7

Comment: I am getting an error C:\xampp\htdocs\zendfblogin\application\controllers\UserController.php(59): TBS\Auth\Adapter\Twitter::getAuthorizationUrl(). When I place a comment tag before the line in user controller and execute I am not getting any errors and my Facebook login is working perfectly fine. But how to remove the above error so that I can login through twitter

Comment: You made my day, This is working. For downloading TBS library Git clone https://github.com/thebestsolution/TBS-Zend-Library.git